# Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"

Tags: firebase, elm

I have a problem when try to import firebase in my project. Previously i installed firebase dependencies in my project. I'm using ELM-SPA.

Error

[image: Error]

My firebase config file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/storage'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };


  //init firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

  //init services
  const projectFirestore = firebase.firestore()
  const projectAuth = firebase.auth()
  const projectStorage = firebase.storage()


  //timestamp
  const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp

  export{
      projectFirestore,
      projectAuth,
      projectStorage,
      timestamp
  }
```

Place where i try to call some firebase functions

```
import { projectAuth } from '../public/config'

const app = Elm.Main.init({
  flags: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storage'))
})

app.ports.save.subscribe(storage => {
  localStorage.setItem('storage', JSON.stringify(storage))
  app.ports.load.send(storage)
})
```

My html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/logo.png" />
</head>
<body>
  <script src="/dist/elm.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it will be better to add the code with the question instead of linking an image. The reason for that is the image hosting service might go down in the future and then the question looses a lot of information in the future. 

It is also more readable to have the information right there.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Comment: Have you looked at the request in the network tab to see what it does return?

Comment: Everyting is fine in the network. But still drop MIME type error in the console

Comment: _How_ do you know that "everything is fine in the network"?

Comment: You are rigth , i missed js on config, but now i have Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../" in config file.

Comment: These `import` paths are being resolved by the browser, and the browser doesn't know what `'firebase/app'` is. You probably want to use a bundler that will let you reference node modules, and then serve the bundled output from your `public` folder. Examples of bundlers include [WebPack](https://webpack.js.org/), [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/), [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/), and [Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/).

Comment: WebPack solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In `main.js` you're importing `'../public/config'`, which is what the error is referring to. This is all happening in the browser, so the browser is trying to load that URL and failing. You could change the import to `'./config.js'`, but if you have secret information in that config file you shouldn't be exposing it to the public. In that case, you'll need to introduce some server-side component where you store your secrets.

Comment: Was the error about `config` or `config.js`? Maybe you need to hard-refresh to see the changed files?

Comment: I had a similar problem and when putting the `.js` it worked

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just had a typo in the name of the component I was trying to render. I was importing and attempting to render `approversSettings` when the name of the component was actually `approverSettings`. It was trying to import from `approversSettings` which did not exist.